# Как сделать iOS приложение из сайта?

Tags: iphone, ios, html5, apple

Далёкий от техники клиент спрашивает далёкого от разработки под iPhone разработчика:

> > — У меня есть красивый сайт-визитка из трёх страниц! Хочу его в виде приложения в своём айфоне видеть. Только для себя, без App Store'ов там всяких.

А у меня, разработчика, имеется MacBook, XCode, Adobe Creative Suite. Нет сертификата разработчика Apple.

Как реализовать пожелание клиента наименее затратно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без сертификата разработчика вы не сможете поставить на *невзломанный* iPhone ничего (имеются в  виду программы), кроме приложений из AppStore. Собственно, поэтому конкретно ваша задача в предложенных условиях не решается (максимум чего можно добиться - ответ пользователя [@filchakov](/users/7756/filchakov)).

Comment: Пока разрабатываю приложение, на свой iPhone же я как-то смог бы ставить свою разработку?

Comment: @sergiks,  
> Без сертификата разработчика вы не сможете...

Comment: Хор. Получу сертификат скоро. $99 за год, клиент пусть оплатит. Следующий шаг по вашей версии наименее затратного/сложного пути решения?

Comment: Создается проект приложения в Xcode, в папку с проектом кладется сайт (прям просто копируется корневой каталог с сервера - у вас там без php, кстати?), в самом приложении всего один экран, на который кладётся т.н. WebView, затем в коде просто открываете index.html в этом WebView. Всё, работаете как в обычном браузере дальше  (по умолчанию никаких кнопок назад\вперед нет, но добавить их - дело пяти минут).    
Ну, разве что при этом нужно будет все абсолютные пути в html-документах (если такие есть, что мало вероятно) заменить на относительные.

Comment: Гениально просто. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой инструмент, *платформа*, или как его лучше назвать, в общем: [**`PhoneGap`**](http://phonegap.com/). Эта *штука* позволяет адаптировать свои **`веб-приложения`** [практически **под любую мобильную платформу**](http://phonegap.com/about/features).

Comment: Спасибо, в закладки. Для разработки по iOS потребуются все те же Mac и сертификат.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Похожая штука - Corona от Ansca Mobile.

Comment: corona -платная, в отличие от phonegap

Comment: Мне кажется, что "веб-приложения" и сайт-визитка - это несколько разные вещи. Поэтому ни PhoneGap, ни Corona тут не нужны совершенно.

Answer (score 1):

В открытом браузере sfafri нажать стрелочку (которая будет над кнопкой home) выбрать "Добавить домой" Все! это самый быстрый способ без лицензии разработчика.

Comment: Да, отличный метод : )
Всё бы супер, да без доступа в сеть это предприятие накрывается медным тазиком.

Answer (score 0):

[Плагин](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-iphone-ui/) под JQuery и [демо](http://iphone.hohli.com/).

Comment: jQuery это хорошо. Но как это всё «упаковать» под iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Джэйл брэйк - это без аппсторов всяких и скорей всего WebKit.

Comment: > скорей всего WebKit.  
  
А есть альтернативы какие-нибудь?

Comment: Есть, взять дизайн сайта и все хардкодно забить, не сеть не WebKit не нужен :)

Comment: @x86-64, если уж мы заговорили о хардкоре, то почему бы не показывать скриншоты веб-страниц, а в нужных местах накладывать кнопки, стилизованные под ссылки для перехода между скриншотами? :)

Comment: Хардкор != Хардкод, а вдруг контента много,  все на один скриншот не залезет :)

Comment: Ага, а потом все скриншоты склеивать и на скролл кидать :)

Comment: Склеивать? Зачем?

Comment: Ага, с каким разрешением скриншоты будем делать?

Comment: @x86-64 с достаточным, чтобы контент вместить. Это имеет значение? Все равно сколл придется юзать, если конечно сайт под мобильные устройства не отпимизирован.